# How to exclude a word in latex dictionary

Tags: texmaker, spelling, dictionaries

I just added a spell checker to texmaker and it works really well, except for one thing:

since I'm italian, the right way to say "is" is "è" and not "é", so I would like that every time I write "é", it gets underlined and suggested to be rewritten as "è".

I just looked in the .dic file and, in fact, there is only the right accent, but anyway writing "é" is not recognised as an error.

> How could I make a list of "excluded words" in my dictionary?

Comment: Sorry, but this is beyond the scope of the site. What the spell-checker does cannot be controlled from the TeX side. Neither the single ê is signalled as wrong.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is off-topic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is a TeXMaker bug. Specifically, it does't check single-character words properly if at all

(This is mainly to wrap up my comments and testing.)

I have installed the latest TeXMaker for Ubuntu 20.04 from `https://www.xm1math.net/texmaker/` (I use TeX Live 2021 from CTAN, not the version of TeX Live 2019 provided by this Ubuntu). I pointed TeXMaker to an it_IT.dic that does not contain é (I've searched, and the only entry starting é is élite). Hunspell is configured to use the exact same file, which is located in `/usr/share/hunspell`.

My initial test file was:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}

é

formaggio

è
\end{document}
```

(I must have a one-track mind; that was the first Italian word I could think of).

Hunspell detects é as an error.

TeXMaker's full spell check (F7) throws an error ("file not found", but it doesn't say which file).  I don't propose to track that down.  But its inline spell check doesn't highlight é as an error, whether I set Italian or English. It does highlight other errors, like random English words in Italian and formaggio in English.

Suspecting it might be an issue with handling one-character words, I tried `te, tè, té` - the last should be detected as an error unlike the other two.  That was correctly found.

Setting English again, I noticed that é, e, and è weren't highlighted.  Further testing showed that a (of course correct in English), á, and à aren't highlighted either.  In fact, if I type out the alphabet with spaces between the letters, I get no red underline.

Some spell checkers have an option to ignore single character words; TeXMaker doesn't seem to, or you could turn it off.

Comment: Thank you really much for your effort. Since this question was off-topic, I take the occasion to ask you another off-topic question: what ide are you used to use to write in latex?

Comment: @Gabrielekk I tend to use the same programmer's editor for everything (currently jEdit) - Python, html, general note-taking, TeX, javascript etc.  It's old fashioned but it works for me - I like having the same menus, regex find & replace, that kind of thing. Then, old-fashioned again, I compile from the terminal - no issues with messages being "helpfully" hidden by the IDE and that kind of thing

Comment: This is a very clear point.. never thought about that. Thank you again for your help!